# Schengen visit visa and Romanian visit visa

Tags: visas, schengen, romania

I soon would like to visit Romania and at first I was thinking I will apply for a Romanian private visit visa, however, there is a good chance that during my stay in Romania that we will have a trip to other countries within the Schengen area.

In that case, which type of visa would I need and at which consular authority? (I am from Egypt)

Answer (score 1):

> In that case, which type of visa would I need?

You will need a C Short-Stay uniform visa, that allows you to stay for 90 days in a 180-day period during your visa validity

---

> at which consular authority?

It depends where you want to go in Schengen

The Schengen visa code states :

> The Member State competent for examining and deciding on an
> application for a uniform visa shall be:
>
> (a)
>
> the Member State whose territory constitutes the sole destination of
> the visit(s);
>
> (b)
>
> if the visit includes more than one destination, the Member State
> whose territory constitutes the main destination of the visit(s) in
> terms of the length or purpose of stay; or
>
> (c)
>
> if no main destination can be determined, the Member State whose
> external border the applicant intends to cross in order to enter the
> territory of the Member States.

A main destination can be taken as the longest stay **or** if you have your main reason to visit the Schengen area there (a meeting, familiy event...)

Comment: I understand but most of my stay will be in Romania, which is not part of Schengen yet, in that case how would I justify getting a Schengen visa?

Comment: @cazanova By whatever the reason for you visiting the Schengen Area is (tourism, business...), your stay in Romania is mostly irrelevant here

Comment: If Romania is the most important part of your travel you have to apply for a Romanian visa and either not go to the Schengen area or apply for a separate Schengen visa. The use of a Schengen visa for Romania is not a good reason to apply for a Schengen visa.